# How can I refer to a database deployed from the same DACPAC file, but with a different db name?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd, dacpac

**Background**

I have a multi-tenant scenario and a unique Sql Server project that will be deployed into multiple databases instances on the same server. There will be one db for each tenant, plus one "model" db.

The "model" database serves three purposes:

1. Force some "system" data to be always present in each tenant database
2. Serves as an access point for users with a special permission to edit system data (which will be punctually synced to all tenants)
3. When creating a new tenant, the database will be copied and attached with a new name representing the tenant

There are triggers that checks if the modified / deleted data within tenant db corresponds to "system" data inside the "model" db. If it does, an error is raised saying that system data cannot be altered.

**Issue**

So here's a part of the trigger that checks if deletion can be allowed:

```
IF DB_NAME() <> 'ModelTenant' AND EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        [deleted].*
    FROM
        [deleted]
            INNER JOIN [---MODEL DB NAME??? ---].[MySchema].[MyTable] [ModelTable]
            ON  [deleted].[Guid] = [ModelTable].[Guid]
    )
BEGIN;
    THROW 50000, 'The DELETE operation on table MyTable cannot be performed. At least one targeted record is reserved by the system and cannot be removed.', 1
END
```

I can't seem to find what should take the place of --- MODEL DB NAME??? --- in the above code that would allow the project to compile properly. When refering to a completely different project I know what to do: use a reference to the project that's represented with an SQLCMD variable. But in this scenario the project reference is essentially the same project; only on a different database. I can't seem to be able to add a self-reference in this manner.

What can I do? Does SSDT offers some kind of support for such a scenario?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to view data in the Model database or one of the tenants? If it is the model just put that name inside your brackets where you have it. If it is a tenant database this is a lot more challenging as you will likely need dynamic sql. But that depends on the context of your code. What database is this code executing on?

Comment: @SeanLange I can't just put the name of the model database in the brackets. The project will fail to compile the DACPAC, giving an "unsolved reference to object" error. Agreed, in pure TSQL, putting the db's name there would be the thing to do, but I'm using SSDT here. :)

Comment: Why not move your sql code to a procedure? You need to do that at some point to separate the business/display layer from the data layer.

Comment: @SeanLange I can't, the procedure won't have access to trigger's deleted / inserted tables. And even if it did, I'll still need a JOIN across two databases. How would it be different in a procedure?

Comment: Oh yeah...this is a trigger. My bad. That seems like a bug in DACPAC to me as the syntax is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SeanLange Using the dbname would be valid syntax in pure TSQL, yes. However, SSDT uses DACPAC models as references to compile against. And the real issue here is more about having no actual "DbModel" project reference. So *technically* this isn't a bug per se. I'd just need to figure out how a project can "reference" to itself across different databases - if it can be done at all.

Comment: I'll try adding a dummy project I can refer to without enforcing object referencing and see if it works. I absolutely hate it but at this point my imagination can't do much better I'm afraid.

Comment: Don't include the database name or the schema in your code. This will assume the current database.

Comment: @Steve How would I do the JOIN then? I need to check for data's existence on the model db from current tenant's db.

Comment: I guess I am confused by what you are doing but if you have some data you don't want them to be able to delete, model or not, just add another bit field to the table and use it as your flag to not allow deletes.

Comment: @Steve there's kind of a bigger plan behind all this. In the interest of keeping this post as short as possible I narrowed things down to the specific issue of DACPAC referencing.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the model db into a dacpac and adding that as a reference?

Comment: @PeterSchott Wouldn't this create a circular reference issue?

Comment: Nope - circular references are caused by trying to reference a project that then references the current DB. You want to reference another database. Extract it using sqlpackage into a dacpac. Reference that purely for schema purposes as "model". Something like this: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

Comment: @PeterSchott Just tried it and indeed, no circular reference issue but a whole other world of problems. Since the reference path is in fact the build path of the same project, there's a game of "which came first: chicken or egg" going on. Making a change to the project and trying to build it will sometimes fail as the referenced DACPAC is actually the last built version of the same project in which changes doesn't (yet) exist.

Comment: We used an external reference path (e.g., C:\Shared\Dacpacs) that could be hit by all projects. Copied the dacpacs there and referenced them - didn't have any issues. As it sounds like you only care about a handful of reference-type tables, you're probably good updating that shared path only when one of those tables changes. We did that for the most part and it worked pretty well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up a Database Variable? You can read under ["Reference aware statements" here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-data-tools-(ssdt)-and-database-references-/). You could then say:

`SELECT * FROM [$(MyModelDb)][MySchema].[MyTable] [ModelTable]`

If you don't have a specific project for `$(MyModelDb)` you can choose the option to "suppress errors by unresolved references...". It's been forever since I've used SSDT projects, but I think that should work.

TIP: If you need to reference 1-table 100-times, you may find it better to create a SYNONM that uses the database variable, then point to the SYNONM in your SPROCs/TRIGGERs. Why? Because that way you don't need to deploy your SPROCs/TRIGGERs to get the variable replaced with the actual value and that can make development smoother.

Comment: Right now my current solution is close to yours. I'm using a dummy project to serve as a mocked reference with the "suppress reference warning" option on. Your post suggests that this option can be set without a project reference. I'd be curious to know how this works. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if SSDT is particularly well-suited to projects of any decent amount of complexity. I can think of one or two ways to most likely accomplish this (especially depending on exactly how you do the publishing / deployment), but I think you would actually lose more than you gain. What I mean by that is: you could add steps to get this to work (i.e. win the battle), but you would be creating a more complex system in order to get SSDT to publish a system that is more complex (and slower) than it needs to be (i.e. lose the war).

Before worrying about SSDT, let's look at why you need/want SSDT to do this in the first place. You have system data intermixed with tenant data, and you need to validate `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations to ensure that the system data does not get modified, and the only way to identify data that is "system" data is by matching it to a home-of-record -- `ModelDB` -- based on GUID PKs.

That theory on identifying what data belongs to the "system" and not to a tenant is your main problem, not SSDT. You are definitely on the right track for a multi-tentant system by having the "model" database, but using it for data validation is a poor design choice: on top of the performance degradation already incurred from using GUIDs as PKs, you are further slowing down all of these `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations by funneling them through a single point of contention since all client DBS need to check this common source.

You would be far better off to include a `BIT` field in each of these tables that mixes system and tenant data, denoting whether the row was "system" or not. Just look at the system catalog views within SQL Server:

- `sys.objects` has an `is_ms_shipped` column
- `sys.assemblies` went the other direction and has an `is_user_defined column`.

So, if you were to add an `[IsSystemData] BIT NOT NULL` column to these tables, your Trigger logic would become:

```sql
IF DB_NAME() <> N'ModelTenant' AND EXISTS
    (
    SELECT del.*
    FROM   [deleted] del
    WHERE  del.[IsSystemData] = 1
    )
BEGIN
    ;THROW 50000, 'The DELETE operation on table MyTable cannot be performed. At least one targeted record is reserved by the system and cannot be removed.', 1;
END;
```

Benefits:

- No more SSDT issue (at least for from this part ;-)
- Faster `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations
- Less contention on the shared resource (i.e. `ModelDB`)
- Less code complexity

Comment: First of all, thanks for a very elaborated answer. :) Now as far as I'm concerned I would be most happy to ditch SSDT altogether, but unfortunately that's not my call to make. My boss is adamant on using Visual Studio and AFAIK Microsoft doesn't offer any alternative for Sql development than SSDT. Plus, we do have some investment made on top of DACPAC and T4 to generate a lot of code automatically. So I doubt dropping all of it is happening any time soon. :(

Comment: Also there is one more role the model db has I forgot to mention: my boss wants to use it to edit system data and sync it to all the tenants. He wants to be using the same app we provide users with, only with a special permission that will allow 1) connecting to the model db in the first place and 2) editing system data and bypassing triggers that prevents it to happen.

Comment: One more thing: the "system" data CANNOT belong to the client. We want data integrity enforced so it's mandatory that the data exists in the DB.

Comment: @Crono Regarding keeping SSDT and having the data exist in each client DB to enforce referential integrity: those are both achieved by my suggestion. I was not saying to get rid of SSDT.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted the meaning of "client" here. :) The sync issue remains, though. See there's a bigger plan behind this. I just narrowed it down to the referencing issue to keep the post as short and relevant as possible. :s

Comment: @Crono True, but the sync issue remains in your current setup as well, right? My suggestion does not prohibit data from being updated within `ModelDB` as it uses the same logic you had which checks `DB_NAME()`. But the sync issue is an entirely different question altogether ;-)

Comment: @Crono Sorry for that confusion. I have updated to swap out "client" for "tenant" to keep with your nomenclature.

Comment: You're right that your suggestion doesn't prohibit syncing. However, using the BIT column would mean that the logic would rely on what each tenant db "knows" about system data, rather than relying on a unique, centered source of system data. Furthermore, we don't expect lots of "system" data so the performance issue on GUID columns shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @Crono Yes, each DB would rely upon its local setting, but that is what you are currently doing now simply by having that data in each tenant DB to begin with. I am just suggesting that you continue using the "model" that you already set up rather than mixing concepts of having the data be local but yet looking to a central repository for parts of it. Which is quite the performance drag. You should either look locally for everything or look centrally for everything, not this mixed approach.

Comment: For a while I was like "the man's right, why don't we just do it that way?". But I just remembered why we don't. :) See, my boss wants a backdoor ability to remove system data, with a twist: this ONE operation must NOT be synced. From then on, the previously "system" data would just live on as user data in tenant dbs, with no equivalent model record. So if we were to use the BIT column technique, we'd have to update the tenants whenever system data is removed from the model. That, in turn, would cause the triggers to throw an exception saying that an update on system data cannot be performed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know requirements just keeps on coming. :p

Comment: @Crono yes, it would help if the Question was updated with this new info :-). I will still say that you are coming at this from the wrong direction by planning for the infrequent use-case and making the frequent use-cases suffer. The BIT field and Trigger logic to prevent the DML operations is easy to handle. Yes, you need to replicate the change out, but you already need a replication mechanism to get data there to begin with. To allow this "disassociation", set CONTEXT_INFO and check that in the Trigger. Or is there a connection property that is different and can be checked in the Trigger?

Comment: @Crono You can even create a local temporary table and simply test for its existence in the Trigger via `IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#AllowSystemDataModification') IS NOT NULL)`. But I would try the other ways first as this method still needs to do some amount of work in `tempdb` to get that info.

Comment: I understand and I'm grateful for you to propose an alternative approach. Unfortunately, my only role in design planning is raising up red flags in meetings. Ultimately the decision to do things in a way or another is not mine to make. :s If it was, the system data would be part of a script that could be used to both initialize a new tenant or "repairing" one. No way the model would be used as a syncing watchdog. :p

Comment: @Crono Ok. So, how do you handle publishing from VS or SqlPackage.exe? Do you publish directly or have one of those generate the SQL script for you?

Comment: @Crono And that is not a joke? He has a full SSDT project set up which manages everything automatically, T4 templates, the works, but then does a manual operation to find differences? Then why mess with SSDT in the first place? I had an idea related to T4 templates, but not sure of any sensible solution if someone is going to do this by hand. And I will forgo asking why your boss is messing with deployments in the first place ;-)

Comment: I think it's mainly because it gives him a perspective on changes that will be posted. He rarely checks things off or on. Also remember that we're using SSDT not because we like it, but because there is no alternative (that we know of) in Visual Studio. In the past we used db projects with plain text files, all being "ALTER" scripts and executed individually. Tables were created directly inside Management Studio and never under a project or even source control. This db project type stopped being supported after VS2008.

Comment: @Crono I understand why you are using SSDT, but as long as you are there and jumping through its hoops (e.g. this Question), you might as well get your monies worth, so to speak. The "Publish Solution" option in the "Build" menu, and SqlPackage.exe, both allow for generating the incremental build SQL script. The statements are in the correct order and account for dependencies, etc. It can be reviewed before running. But why do you think you need VS for doing DB development? I only use it for SQLCLR stuff, nothing else. I use Git and SVN, but not via IDE. Still, SSMS does integrate with VCS.

Comment: Heh, I didn't knew about Sql Script Projects. I thought solutions in SSMS were all oriented on BI and stuff like that. Looks like there is no direct support for TFS (did I mention my boss dislikes anything that's not MS? :) ), but a quick search on Google revealed that there's a way to have it. Of course, using this kind of project would mean losing the code parsing and validation that SSDT provides, which is the ONE thing that made us like it. It also takes away the code we wrote around DACPAC model, on which our T4 templates heavily relies. Still, it's worth mentioning at the next meeting.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to referencing another database project, you can produce a dacpac, then reference the dacpac as a database reference in "same server, different database" mode.

Comment: Do you mean referencing the same DACPAC file that's getting built by the same project?

Comment: Yes and no. What I'm saying is to add a standalone dacpac file to the project and then add a database reference to it.  The source of the dacpac file could be your project's build output or it could be a dacpac that's extracted from your database using SqlPackage.exe. Regardless, you can place a copy of that dacpac file into your project right next to the *.sql files, to be used as a reference for your model.

Comment: Either way, this will mean that at some point the referenced package will contain different elements from the yet-to-be-compiled project. This difference may cause the build to fail, even though technically the code is good. One way to prevent this from happening is to ignore unresolved objects for this referenced DACPAC, but at this point I might just as well use a dummy DACPAC that has no elements at all...